# Why the game window closes after specific time?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Why the window that created by `SDL Game Library` are automatically closed after specific time.
I know the reason is `SDL_Delay()` function, but if not used that function, the game will appear runtime error.

How can I create a window that continuously work without appear in specific period time ?

**My code(Simplest code):**

```
SDL_Window *window;
SDL_Renderer *render;

int main(int argc, char* args[]){

   if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) >= 0){
      window = SDL_CreateWindow("Simple game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
      if(window != 0){
         render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
      }

   }else{
      return 1;
   }

   SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(render, 0, 0, 0, 255);
   SDL_RenderClear(render);
   SDL_RenderPresent(render);

   SDL_Delay(3000);     
   SDL_Quit();

   return 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop forever and call SDL update screen functions. Read LazyFoo tutorials found here: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials

Or here a short code to get you started:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL/SDL.h"                    // basic SDL
#include <string>

const int       SCREEN_WIDTH    = 640;
const int       SCREEN_HEIGHT   = 480;
const int       SCREEN_BBP      = 32;   // bits per-pixel

SDL_Surface*    screen          = NULL; // display screen 
SDL_Event       event;                  // grab events


using namespace std;

bool init() {

    // initialize SDL
    if(SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) == -1)
        return false;

    //the screen image
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 
                              SCREEN_BBP, SDL_SWSURFACE );
    if(!screen) {
        cout << "error creating screen" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    //Set the window caption 
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Event Test", NULL );

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{   
    try
    {
        // make sure the program waits for a quit
        bool quit = false;

        cout << "Starting SDL..." << endl; 

        // Start SDL 
        if(!init()) {
            cout << "initialize error" << endl;
            return false;
        }

        // main loop
        while( quit == false )  
        {
            if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))  
            {                       
                // The x button click
                if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)  
                {
                    //quit the program
                    quit = true;
                }

            }

            // Fill the screen white 
            SDL_FillRect( screen, &screen->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB( 
                screen->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );


            //Update screen
            if(SDL_Flip(screen) == -1)
                return -1;
        }
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cerr << "exception caught: " << e.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I'm using `1.2`.

Comment: Why after modify my code, and add `while loop` the window become frozen, no control.

Comment: @LionKing what does your `while` loop look like?

Comment: `while(quit == false){
   SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(render, 0, 0, 0, 255);
   SDL_RenderClear(render);
   SDL_RenderPresent(render);

   if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))  
   {                       
      if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)  
      {
         quit = true;
       }

   }


   if(SDL_UpdateWindowSurface);
        return -1;
   }`, 
your code unfortunately need to modifications to compatible with `SDL v2.0`.

Comment: Here is `SDL1.2` to `SDL2.0` mitigation document: http://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide

Comment: This will take some time to review that article, no problem, I will give you the best answer for your effort. congratulation.